# Задваиваются Яндекс.Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

написан код, который считывает введенный город и показывает карту с этим городом. Проблема, что при первом вызове создается одна карта и всё ок, при повторных вызовах создаются две карты одного города, причем обе находятся внутри divа. В чем может быть проблема?

```
  if(myPlainObject){
                        myPlainObject.destroy();
                        myPlainObject = null;
                    }
                    var myPlainObject = $(function(){
                        ymaps.ready(function () {
                            var map;
                            ymaps.geolocation.get().then(function (res) {
                                var mapContainer = $('#map'),
                                    bounds = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'),
                                    mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
                                        bounds,
                                        [mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height()]
                                    );
                                createMap(mapState);
                            }, function (e) {
                                createMap({
                                    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                                    zoom: 9
                                });
                            });

                            function createMap (state) {
                                var city = document.getElementById('basket_city').value;
                                ymaps.geocode(city).then(function (res) {

                                    if(myMap){
                                        myMap.destroy();
                                        myMap = null;
                                    }
                                    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                                        center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
                                        zoom : 10
                                    });
                                    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                                        clusterize: true,
                                        gridSize: 32,
                                        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
                                    });


                                    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
                                    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
                                    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "https://example.ru/json"
                                    }).done(function (data) {
                                        objectManager.add(data);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = myPlainObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не совсем понятно как в примере используется destroy(). В документации к API есть такой метод, но он применятся только к объекту класса ymaps.Map и служит для очистки dom-элемента, а вы пытаетесь применить метод к переменной, в которую обернута вся функция вызова: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/map-docpage/#map__add_and_destroy

Во-вторых, не понятно зачем было оборачивать функцию и использовать innerHTML. Вашу задачу можно решить средствами API. То есть код:

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
 var map;
 ymaps.geolocation.get().then(function (res) {
  var mapContainer = $('#map'),
   bounds = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'),
   mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
    bounds,
    [mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height()]
   );
  createMap(mapState);
 }, function (e) {
  createMap({
   center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
   zoom: 9
  });
 });

 function createMap (state) {
  var city = document.getElementById('basket_city').value;
  ymaps.geocode(city).then(function (res) {

   if(myMap){
    myMap.destroy();
    myMap = null;
   }
   var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
    zoom : 10
   });
   objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 32,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true
   });


   objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
   objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
   myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
   $.ajax({
    url: "https://example.ru/json"
   }).done(function (data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
   });
  });
 }
});
```

будет работать точно так же, как и код из вашего примера.